# phoneGap + Eclipse PLugin install Issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

below error occured when i'm trying to install plugin to eclipse. i never already install that to eclipse and this is my fresh copy of eclipse helios

please help me to sort out this issue

```
  "JavaScript Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JavaScript Development Tools 1.2.4.v201207042009 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group 1.2.4.v201207042009)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    JavaScript Debug Core 1.0.1.v201008170101 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.core
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with eclipse classic version and now issue is sorted